# Redisson FastRemove on multiple keys not working

Tags: java, java-8, redis, redisson

I am trying to delete keys from redisson local cache map and it doesn't seem to work.
I have a map named : `reportersCache` of type `RedissonLocalCachedMap`.
The keys of this map are of type long.
For example, lets say I have 2 records for keys 1,2.
When I call `reportersCache.fastRemove(Arrays.asList(1,2))` I see that these records are still in redis and were not deleted at all.
On the other hand, if I perform a single remove for each key, the do get deleted (`reportersCache.fastRemove(1); reportersCache.fastRemove(2)`)

Am I doing something wrong? How can I perform HDEL correctly using redisson?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> When I call reportersCache.fastRemove(Arrays.asList(1,2)) I see that these records are still in redis and were not deleted at all.

`fastRemove()` accepts var args parameters and not a list. You need to pass array instead of list.